# Few Questions on Hyperledger Fabric Capabilities and FabToken Transactions Between Multiple Blockchains

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, enterprise

I am learning Hyperledger Fabric; I would like to clarify my understanding of Fabric's capability and ask few questions. I appreciate your input.

1. My understanding is that one can create a blockchain for an enterprise. Other enterprises can join the same blockchain to transact on there, correct?
2. For a given enterprise, can I create multiple blockchains that connect to eachother, or to one main blockchain within that same enterprise? Similar to how parachains and relay chain work in Polkadot?
3. Say I mint a coin for Enterprise 1 on Blockchain 1. Lets say Enterprise 2 comes into Blockchain 1 to interact with Enterprise 1. Lets say Enterprise 2 gathered some of the coins from Blockchain 1 and wants to use them on their own fabric blockchain, Blockchain 2. Can coins minted on Blockchain 1 can be used on Blockchain 2?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: did u have any other resources that answers your questions ?